# How do I align the caption in a subfigure?

Tags: graphics, subcaption

I have a figure which is composed of three subfigures. Two of them are expected to occupy the left side of the screen, while the last will be on the right side. I want the sub caption on the one to the right to align with the sub caption of the lower one of the two at the left side. How do I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption,float}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  %\caption{Figures showing the behavior of a type II superconductor.}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{figures/type-2-magnetization-color.png}
    \caption{Figure showing a the relation between applied magnetic field and magnetization for a type II superconductor. The S stands for superconducting phase, the MS for mixed state, and the N stand for normal phase.}
    \includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{figures/type-2-meissner-color.png}
    \caption{Figure showing the phase transition between a normal metal and a type II superconductor. The S stands for superconducting phase, the MS for mixed state, and the N stand for normal phase.}
    \label{fig:type-2-magnetization}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{figures/ybco.jpg}
    \caption{Figure showing the the vortices in YBCO, a type II superconductor. © Frederick S. Wells, Alexey V. Pan, X. Renshaw Wang, Sergey A. Fedoseev \& Hans Hilgenkamp, CC Wikimedia.}
   %\vspace{1cm}
    \label{fig:vortices}
  \end{subfigure}
  \label{fig:type-2-relationship-h-t}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I've taken the liberty of editing your code to make it (minimally) compilable.

Answer (score 2):

Q: "I want the sub caption on the one to the right to align with the sub caption of the lower one of the two at the left side. How do I do that?"

A: Just change both instances of `\begin{subfigure}[t]` to `\begin{subfigure}[b]`.

In case you haven't guessed it already: `[t]` means alignment at the **t**op, and `[b]` means alignment at the **b**ottom.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example) -- note that I would advocate making the graphs and captions equally wide:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % optional
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{subcaption,ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=RaggedRight}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm,width=\textwidth]{figures/type-2-magnetization-color.png}
\caption{Figure showing a the relation between applied magnetic field and magnetization for a type II superconductor. The S stands for superconducting phase, the MS for mixed state, and the N stands for normal phase.}

\medskip
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm,width=\textwidth]{figures/type-2-meissner-color.png}
\caption{Figure showing the phase transition between a normal metal and a type II superconductor. The S stands for superconducting phase, the MS for mixed state, and the N stand for normal phase.}
\label{fig:type-2-magnetization}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm,width=\textwidth]{figures/ybco.jpg}
\caption{Figure showing the the vortices in YBCO, a type II superconductor. ©~Frederick S. Wells, Alexey V. Pan, X. Renshaw Wang, Sergey A. Fedoseev~\& Hans Hilgenkamp, CC Wikimedia.}
\label{fig:vortices}
\end{subfigure}

%% You need a \caption statement for the overall 'figure' env.
\label{fig:type-2-relationship-h-t}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```